# How to pass an array of structs to a DLL function using cpython?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes, cpython

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct_data {
    int price;
    char list[255];
    int count;
};

__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall testcall(struct struct_data *array_data) {

    int i = 0;
    while(array_data[i].price != 0) {           // array_data is guaranteed to have a zero somewhere inside memory allocated for the array
        printf("%d\n", array_data[i].price);
        i++;
    }

}
```

I try to call it from Python using cpython as follows:

```py
# C Backend imports
import os
import sys
import ctypes

# load DLL
dll = ctypes.WinDLL('C:\\Users\\user\Documents\\Pelles C Projects\\MarketlibDLL\\MarketlibDLL.dll')

class struct_data(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('price', ctypes.c_int),
        ('list', ctypes.c_char * 255),
        ('count', ctypes.c_int),
    ]

d = struct_data() * 100    # I try to do:   struct struct_data d[100]; 
d[0].price = 100
d[0].list = "ABC"
d[0].count = 3
d[1].price = 0

dll.testcall.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(struct_data)]
dll.testcall(d)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-36161e840b5f> in <module>
----> 1 d = struct_data() * 100
      2 d[0].price = 100
      3 d[0].list = "ABC"
      4 d[0].count = 3
      5 d[1].price = 0

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'struct_data' and 'int'
```

Comment: @golobich see edited answer, I am trying to create a 100 items array of struct_data's that I can pass to the C function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) has all the required info (the **Arrays** section contains an example that maps perfectly over the current scenario).

Modify your code to (split in 2 lines for readability):

```py
struct_data_array_100 = struct_data * 100  # !!! This is a type (array consisting of 100 struct_data elements) !!!
d = struct_data_array_100()  # Instantiate the array type
#d[0].price ...
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list of 100 `struct_data` you need to multiply the list not the data:

```
d = [struct_data()] * 100
```

This is the same as writing:

```
d = [struct_data() for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: I want a C array of 100 struct_data objects, which is different from a list. I finally learned I have to do this: `d = (struct_data * 100)()`